# Regime switching stochastic systems references

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm looking for some good references discussing regime switching stochastic systems (Stochastic systems with markovian jump process) and their solutions.

Given a Continuous-time Markov Chain $\xi$ with state space $\mathbb S$, a regime switching stochastic sysem is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
dX_t&=b(t,X_t,\xi_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t,\xi_t)dW_t\\
X_0&=x_0, \xi_0=w\in \mathbb S
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: This area is somewhat vast; for starters, see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-21/issue-1/Exponential-ergodicity-for-Markov-processes-with-random-switching/10.3150/13-BEJ577.pdf or https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/15M1024512?casa_token=dfCOf5gGB9sAAAAA:sJOuraKjzSWUDDiS7VMnluR5FHDPLiG7_m0Z3NF3SUt_FfnYUjBFXaIsTaYiZZ2U-jnMUD3yIi3N and references therein

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you !

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Just checked it. My area exactly is the stochastic differential equations that depend on a markov chain $\xi$ i.e$dX_t=b(t,X_t,\xi_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t,\xi_t)dW_t$. I couldn't access this book (https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Differential-Equations-Markovian-Switching/dp/1860947018) so I'm looking for similar references. Thanks again !